# Strange black mark in mesh(Not backface)

Tags: mesh, smooth

When look closely model body, i saw this mark
[image]

Checked Diffuse, Normal, Specular maps there anything like that.
I smooth nothing works, recalcuate normals same
In weight paint all body is dark blue
Olso body object had no visible seams there(except neck, arms and foots)

Comment: may be something about uv map?

Comment: Or a duplicate vertex?